# Case statement in where clause using not like and is not null

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I'm pulling data from an existing table using a stored procedure that has some yes or no choices that the user picks on the front end through a checkbox. I want to limit writing a bunch of different `If` statements for every choice they make.

This portion of my where clause works. Data is either `Y` or `N` for this column.

`Where... and IsSigned = Case When @IncludeSigned = 'Y' then IsSigned else 'N' end`

I would like to add to the where using `is not null` and `not like` if this is possible between the square brackets. So far I have

`and SignatureType = case when @IncludeElectronic = 'Y' then Type else [NOT like electronic] end`

also

`and ReviewDate = Case When @HasReviewDate = 'Y' then [ReviewDate is not null] else null end`

Comment: Not really sure what you're goal is here, but you can't put a boolean expression in the `THEN` and `ELSE` part of a `CASE` expression. A `CASE` expression returns a scalar value not a boolean result. Sample Data and Expected results would be useful here.

Comment: You can write subquery but you cannot add sql statement like what you are trying to do. You can look for `dynamic queries`

Comment: As Larnu wrote, you don't really understand the CASE expression and how to use it. Erland has written an extensive discussion about [dynamic searching](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html). His home page also has other comprehensive and useful discussions on common sql topics - worth a bookmark.

Comment: It's generally better to use `AND`/ `OR` constructions instead of `case` _expressions_ in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help you use AND/OR instead of case

```
where (ReviewDate is not null or @HasReviewDate = 'Y' ) And (....)
```

ie  when @HasReviewDate = 'Y' query will return the records with ReviewDate is not null 
and when   @HasReviewDate != 'Y' then  query will return the records with ReviewDate is  null

Comment: I was able to meet all my criteria and return the results best with this answer. Didn't know you could encapsulate `and/or` in parenthesis and it treats them seperately .

Answer (score 1):

think of it this way:-

Your first case statement has two possible results:-

> IsSigned = 'Y'
>    IsSigned = 'N'

Your subsequent ones have problems as they don't make sense syntactically. So the second one as written returns

> SignatureType =  Type
>   SignatureType =  [NOT like electronic]

and your third:

> ReviewDate = [ReviewDate is not null]
>    ReviewDate =  null end

SO the operator has to be before the case statement and apply to all of the results of the case statement.

For example

> WHERE myfield not like CASE WHEN thatfield=1 THEN 'Fish' ELSE 'Chips END

would produce either

> myfield not like 'Fish'
>
> myfield not like 'Chips'

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can not use in this way, apart of that, the impact that is not like can have inside your query can be high, my recommendation changes the strategy that you are using.

Comment: You cannot exacrly know this. He need to check explain plan

Comment: Generally, we have performance problem associated with this kind of scenario, but you right, he has not shared the Execution Plan for confirming, but it is worth to read this article about it: https://dotnetvibes.com/2016/10/26/searching-data-in-sql-tables-impact-on-performance/